# Hostname only seems to be 127.0.0.1 for Apache JMeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I try jmeter-server on linux (**centos6**). It says "Created remote object: localhost:44750" . But the hostname should not be  "**localhost**" . It should be hostname as like "10.6.149.95".

So my jmeter master is failed, if I try the following command at another server :

> ./jmeter -n -t  myRequest.jmx -R 10.6.149.95

or

> ./jmeter -n -t  myRequest.jmx -r

**The failed logs** :

```
Created the tree successfully using /root/myRequest.jmx
Configuring remote engine for 10.6.149.95
Using remote object: 127.0.0.1:44750 (null)
Starting remote engines
Starting the test @ Wed Sep 11 14:01:48 TRST 2013 (1378897308614)
An error occurred: method java.util.ResourceBundle.containsKey with signature (Ljava.lang.String;)Z was not found.
```

My `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
10.6.149.95 host-10-6-149-95
```

I've tried it in two different version of Java (openjdk6-bin-1.6.0.2_22 and jdk1.7.0_25)

**Why the hostname is 127.0.0.1? How to solve this problem?**

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

1. I used a static IP instead of DHCP server. (I had used DHCP server)
2. I add to "./jmeter-server"

   > RMI_HOST_DEF="-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.6.149.95

   or

   > RMI_HOST_DEF="-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$(ifconfig eth0 | sed -n
   >   '2s/[^:]*:[ \t]*([^ ]*) .*/\1/p')"
3. I  add to "./jmeter"

   > `JVM_ARGS="-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.6.149.95`

   ```
    or
   ```

   > JVM_ARGS="-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$(ifconfig eth0 | sed -n
   >   '2s/[^:]*:[ \t]*([^ ]*) .*/\1/p')"

Comment: I asked same question in the mail list : http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jmeter-user/201309.mbox/browser

Comment: `RMI_HOST_DEF` and `JVM_ARGS` lines do not have to be added to jmeter-server and jmeter executables, these variables are to be used in command-line like this:
`JVM_ARGS="-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.6.149.95" ./jmeter -n -t myRequest.jmx -r`
If you prefer, you can edit `/etc/hosts` file's first line changing the localhost IP (127.0.0.1) with machine's current IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved.

My server default java version is 1.5. I upgrade java version.

**jmeter doesn't support java 1.5**

Answer (score 0):

As I recall JMeter by default binds to localhost when run as server in [certain cases](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jakarta-jmeter/+bug/589042), so either you need to connect your slaves via a SSH tunnel or use the parameter `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.6.149.95` on the `jmeter-server` command line, in order to bind to the LAN IP.

Cheers,

Comment: I did but It didn't change.

Comment: Sorry, missed a dash in front of the D.